# Combining highcharts with large data and irregular data intervals

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to combine highchart Area chart and line chart like so - https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time. This works fine if there is less data. If one of the chart datas is more, I do not see anything but the tooltips.But when I zoom in and zoom out or change the window size, I see both the charts. I am attaching a screenshot for reference.
[image: chart looks like this on load before zooming in]

[image: When i zoom in and zoom out, I see the second chart too like so ->]

I have tried using the highchart boost module but no luck. Any Idea why?

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1ydrjuk/

Comment: I am somehow not able to recreate this issue on Jsfiddle. When i copy the series data, it all displays fine on the fiddle but the same doesn't work on the app.

Comment: Perhaps you can reproduce it in an Angular environment in codesandbox? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4